# PIP and setup.py with local requirements

Tags: python, pip, distutils

I have a package that will be installed with PIP, let say it's names PackageA.
PackageA has a one requirement, written out in requirements.txt to PackageB.
Like:
file://../../PackageB

PackageB should require another PackageC, using setup.py or requrements.txt. All packages are placed localy. How should be it done?

setup.py could not have requirements to a local packages. 
I do not now how place in Package B requirement to a local PackageC

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pip install --download-cache=<cachedir> packageA`

Where cachedir is the directory with the dependency packages.

Try to fiddle with `--no-download` and `--no-deps`

Check `pip install --help` for more information.